# What experiments did Faraday do leading to his motor?

Tags: electromagnetism, history

I am trying to understand Faraday's notebook entries on the day he discovered his motor. For example, in drawing 2a. I imagine that he held a magnet (denoted by the arrow) horizontally behind a wire connected to a battery and noticed a strong attraction between the wire and the magnet. However, a similar interpretation doesn't make sense for drawing 2b. Did he hold two magnets offset left and right: one in front and one behind the wire? If so, was the wire repulsed from both magnets? Why wouldn't there be an attraction between the wire and the magnet behind the wire as with 2a.? What effect would slightly shifting a magnet have as in drawings 3a and 3b.? What do the dots on the arrows represent? 
[image: Faraday Notebook entries]

Comment: Perhaps he also realised that the other part of the wire repelled the magnet and gave him the conclusion that current flowing through wire makes it a magnet with a well defined polarity depending on direction of current. This would be his most important realisation from there the idea of an electric motor can be conceived pretty easily with some trials and errors.

Comment: cf. [the Nat'l MagLab's page on and animation of the Faraday Motor](https://nationalmaglab.org/education/magnet-academy/watch-play/interactive/faraday-motor)